# Egui empty scroll that scrolls infinite

Tags: rust, egui

I am looking for a way how I can get a infinity scroll in egui. I dont want to add items to it because its supposed to be infinite. I rather want an empty scroll that is empty and scrolls infinite. Based on that I want to offset the content manually. It should kepp fetching new content and dispose of the old one. Does anyone know how to?

I belive plots work like this. How can i implement the scroll like this?

I added the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the sollution. I found i after looking through plot
let scroll_delta = ui.input(|i| i.scroll_delta);